# Multiple Range selection using macro

Tags: vba, excel

It is possible to make the Range same as "OR" condition...
Any ideas to solve it?

```
Sub search()

Dim myArray As Variant
Dim mRange As Range
Dim mFCell As String
Dim mCell As Range
Dim mName As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer

myArray = Range("J2:J4").Value

mName = myArray.Value

finalrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

Set mRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")
Set mCell = mRange.Find(What:=mName, MatchCase:=False, lookAt:=xlPart)

For i = 2 To finalrow

           If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = mCell.Value Then
               mFCell = mCell.Address
               Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1)).Copy
               Range("I1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
               'Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
               Set mCell = mRange.FindNext(mCell)

           End If
Next i

End Sub
```

So, I need to find the multipleRange that was explain in comment.

Comment: Are you asking how to put multiple cells (that are not next to each other) in a range? Or is your question about receiving the `.Value` property of multicell ranges?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct
Oh my.. 
Sorry about that I want to ask about receiving the .Value property of multicell range
I go no idea to solve it.

Comment: Do you mean a discontinuous range or a continuous ("rectangular") range?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct continuous I mean the "Rectangular" range. Sorry for messing you around. I have try anything to solve this problems than I'm stuck

Comment: If you post code, always describe what the problem is. What error do you get where?

Answer (score 0):

To assign the values of a range to an array you need to declare the array as a variant

```
Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = someRange.Value
```

The result is an array of dimensions (1 to number of rows) x (1 to number of columns) even if the range is one-dimensional (only one row or column). So the values of

```
myArray = Range("J2:J4").Value
```

would be `myArray(1, 1)`, `myArray(2, 1)`, `myArray(3, 1)`

Comment: I have tried the code but its works only for the first array for the rest its show error "object variable or with block variable not set".

Comment: so it will search the column depends on myArray that was set. So the code is to find myArray in mRange column which is  'mRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") '

Comment: You can't search for a whole array, what are you expecting? That it finds any of the values or all of the values? I'm off the computer for a few days so I'm not going to be able to help you